# Include class from another module in puppet

Tags: module, puppet, manifest

I'm making a test manifest for puppet to install a package with choclatey provider from forge.

If I apply with the file test.pp with the code:

```
class test {
  include chocolatey
  if $::kernel == 'windows' {
    Package { 
      provider => chocolatey, 
    }
  }
  package { '7zip':
    ensure   => installed,
  }
}
```

Is not working and chocolatey doesn't install anything, but if I try without the class with the code:

```
include chocolatey
if $::kernel == 'windows' {
  Package { 
    provider => chocolatey, 
  }
}
package { '7zip':
  ensure   => installed,
}
```

Why? In the first option, why is not working?

Comment: A wild guess, did you simply put the above code in a file and then run it using puppet apply?

Comment: yes, and I started to figure why, in the first example I added `node default { include test}` and it works. It's because that code is have to be part of a module?

Comment: If you just run puppet apply on a class, the class will be defined but it will not be declared. It's like defining a function in shell, and then not actually calling it. So, you need to actually `include` the class somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the test.pp with **puppet apply --test test.pp** but the first code I was only declarating the class but not using it. This code works:

```
class test {
  include chocolatey
  if $::kernel == 'windows' {
    Package { 
      provider => chocolatey, 
    }
  }
  package { '7zip':
    ensure   => installed,
  }
}
include test
```